# how to invalidate one nstimer i need

Tags: iphone, nstimer, invalidation

```
- (void)start{
    NSTimer *mtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(scheduleSomeNSTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)scheduleSomeNSTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSTimer *newtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(showAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)showAction:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSLog(@"action show!");
}
```

if i want invalidate one of the nstimer which schedule by function - `(void)addSomeNSTimer:(NSTimer *)timer`

the application will create newtimer repeatly ,so when i need to invalidate one of these newnstimer ,how can i find the object i need

for example:the application create 4 nstimers and run in loop how can i find one of them and invalidate

Comment: use [Yourtimerobject invalidate];

Comment: i just know all of the nstimer setup by name "newtimer" how can i invalidate one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by below:

As per your feedback, please have a look at below answer.

in .h file, declare on Array:

NSMutableArray *arrTimers;

in .m file, add timer in this array where ever you create the timer.

```
NSTimer *mtimer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];

mtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(scheduleSomeNSTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[arrTimers addObject:mtimer];
```

Then you can invalidate it like below:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = (NSTimer *)[arrTimers objectAtIndex:1];
if(myTimer != nil)
    {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;
    }
```

I hope it will resolve your issue.

---

```
if(timer == mtimer)
{

   if(mtimer != nil)
   {
        [mtimer invalidate];
        mtimer = nil;
   }
}

if(timer == newtimer)
{
    if(newtimer != nil)
    {
        [newtimer invalidate];
        newtimer = nil;
    }
}
```

---

Cheers.

Comment: thx your answer...but i just want to invalidate one of the newtimer i create by - (void)scheduleSomeNSTimer:(NSTimer *)timer

i do not want to invalidate all the nstimer,how can i do that ?

Comment: Then you can declare the Timer object in .h file. Then use that object in scheduleSomeNSTimer method and simple invalidate that object.

Comment: oh..i really want to schedule more one nstimer task ,the number of them is unknow...

Comment: oh...I got your point. I am editing my answer in few minutes. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: one question about the answer,if applicaiton exit,not enter background,the array & timers will be release,should i write the function when the applicaiton did finish launch,the timers must call while my localnotifications had fire

Comment: Hi, yes. then you have to re-initialize all the data. You can store the data in NSUserDefault and then get the data from it and again make the timer calling.

Comment: oh..that's greate idea,should i write action in – applicationWillTerminate: ?

Comment: You can do like (1) When app will terminate then add data into NSUserDefault, and (2) When app will launch then get data from NSUserDefault and make the process. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should keep a reference to the timer in your class and do:

`self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(scheduleSomeNSTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

so whenever you want to invalidate it, just do:

`[self.myTimer invalidate];`

Comment: you should do `[myTimer release];` in your class' `dealloc` method to make sure it gets released.

Comment: some function i shoud run even the application restart

Answer (score 1):

`To_play` is NSTimer object.

```
[To_play invalidate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a NSMutableArray and in Your scheduleSomeNSTimer method, add the newtimer object into the array.  When you invalidate a timer object in this array, you also need to remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without keeping a reference to the timer. Use a flag instead.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL invalidateTimer;
```

Source code related to the Timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(scheduleSomeNSTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)scheduleSomeNSTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
   if(YES == invalidateTimer)
   {
     if([timer isValid])
     {
       [timer invalidate];
       timer = nil;
     }
   }
}
```